# How to return aggregated data from a service in a n-tier architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, aggregate-functions

Let's go with a simple domain here Users and Roles (many-to-many).

In the past when I was learning Entity Framework, I would do something like the following to prevent `1+n` queries to the database:

```
var roleModels = context.Roles.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(
    x => new RoleListModel() {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        Description = x.Description,
        NumberOfUsers = x.Users.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Now that I've encapsulated the data access layer (Entity Framework) behind a service, I'm wondering what is the proper way to accomplish the same thing without making `1+n` database trips?

It seems wrong to return Presentation layer ViewModels from the service layer, which is what my initial gut reaction was telling me to do.

Comment: What's wrong about returning a presentation model from a service layer is that your service layer is dependent upon your presentation layer, which is backwards.  There's noting wrong with creating an identical model in your service layer that you return to your presentation layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** return a presentation-related object from a service call. It defeats the entire purpose of having a nicely decoupled N-tier architecture.

Just create a similar data contract object to return from your service layer,

```
public class RoleContract
{
    ...
}
```

Then at your service layer,

```
var roleContracts = context.Roles
    .OrderBy(role => role.Name)
    .Select(
        role => new RoleContract() {
            Id = role.Id,
            Name = role.Name,
            Description = role.Description,
            NumberOfUsers = role.Users.Count()
        })
    .ToList();
```

You can then accept an instance of such a contract in your `RoleViewModel` constructor and initialize it from there.

Also, I would user a generic class that uses reflection to populate each property on the destination class based property name and property type. It will save you a lot property assignment code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Seems like I sure do a lot of repeating myself in N-Tier development. Should I not be worried about DRY principle?

Comment: I'd recommend [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) for easily converting between similar objects.

Comment: A couple of things, AutoMapper is an awesome tool, but in the long run your performance WILL suffer. As for repeating yourself yes and no, you need to keep a distinction between data objects and view or domain related objects. Because they will grow and change accordingly. View objects will be specific to the view and they will organically change to match for example containing SelectsList types or other view related info, data objects don't need these, this follows the Single Reponsibility Principle.

Comment: @rae1 - Is there a reason I couldn't use the RoleContract directly in the presentation?  Seems like most of the time I'm mapping it to a ViewModel with exactly the same properties which seems like a waste.

Comment: I agree with shenku in terms of the priority of the SRP versus the DRY principle. Now, @Sam, you could perfectly make use of the data contract at the presentation layer; however, do understand its limitation, and try to have a one view -> one view model approach to avoid violating SRP.

Comment: @rae1, makes sense. Can I decorate the data contract with data annotations, or will that mess things up when consuming it outside of MVC?

Comment: On the contrary, if you use the DataAnnotations namespace, most .NET components will correctly process them, either WCF or MVC, etc. Furthermore, it is recommended that your validation logic is centralized in the business layer.